# I'm trying to use java regex to find the first occurrence of a double digit number

Tags: java, regex

My use case is that I have a string that is supposed to hold an address. Unfortunately some instances have junk in the beginning of the string. I want to take the substring of the address string where I have two numeric digits in a row.

For example,

```
1ST MTG-HAZ @230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
```

should become:

```
230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
```

The regex should be able to check for double numbers at the begging of the string, or in the middle.

---

What I have tried so far:

```
if(addrStr.matches("(?s).*[0-9][0-9]")) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9]");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(addrStr);
   if(addrStr.matcher(".*[0-9][0-9]").find(){
   if(matcher.find()){
      addrStr = addrStr.substring(matcher.start(),addrStr.length());
   }
} else {
   addrStr = "No match";
}
```

This code seems to work for some addresses, but not for others. When I used a regex tester, it works for:

```
2ND MTG-SFH PRIM RES@1234 OPEN DOOR DR, HOLLYWOOD FL
```

but not for

```
1ST MTG-HAZ @230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
```

which leads me to believe that the zipcode in the end is throwing it off. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any chance your "correct" addresses will start either at the beginning of the input, or after the occurrence of `@`?

Comment: Try a simple find `(?s)(\d{2}.*)$` replace `$1`

Comment: The basic problem is this part of your regex `.*` starts searching from the _end_ of the string backwards until it finds `\d\d`. Fix that by making it non-greedy `.*?`. Even if it works `.*?` should not be the arbitrator of a match, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace any starts of the input that is followed by two straight digits in this manner:

```
String[] input = {
  "1ST MTG-HAZ @230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042",
  "230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042"
};
for (String s: input) {
    //                               | start of input
    //                               || 0 or more characters, reluctantly quantified
    //                               ||   | followed by 2 digits (non-capturing)
    //                               ||   |            | replace with empty
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^.*?(?=\\d{2,})", ""));
}
```

**Output**

```
230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
```

**Note**

This is less elegant than actually looking for a delimiter.

It seems your "bad" addresses all have a `@` delimiting the start of the "right" address.

I would probably investigate on how to turn that to your advantage instead.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, and far more simple. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: I thought the bad addresses all had the @ character too, but upon further investigation I found instances where they did not. I just used the first few examples for simplification. Your solution appears to be the most simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the order of regex to match the address from the first 2 digts as

```
[0-9][0-9].*$
```

For example see http://regex101.com/r/dN7hO6/1

This would match

```
230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
2ND MTG-SFH PRIM RES
230 MAPLE WAY STREET FLOWERS, WY 23042
```

Comment: @sln i was just about the remove the answer thinking it was wrong and not OP was looking for

Comment: @sln That's the dream :)